# Is there any way we can apply "and" condition to the "terms filter" in Elastic Search?

Tags: elasticsearch

In the below filter query it finds the documents which have any of the terms mentioned. But I am looking for the records that only match all the terms. my_languages is an array field in my index. Is there any simple way for it? I Can add term filters separately and can do it, But is there any simple "add" condition I can apply to these terms. Thank You

```
GET user_info/_search?pretty
    {
      "size": 30,
      "from": 0,
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "my_languages": [
                  8728431,
                  872854,
                  872845
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

Mapping

```
  PUT user_info
    {
      "settings": {
        "number_of_shards": 1,
        "max_ngram_diff": 35
      },
      "mappings": {
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "email": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "my_languages": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "updated_by": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Test Data

```
POST /user_info/_doc/
{
  "id": 10,
  "email": 2020,
  "my_languages": [
    8728431,
    872854,
    872845
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to made a bool query

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [ 
        {
          "match": {
            "my_languages": "8728431"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "my_languages": "872845"
          }
        }
,
        {
          "match": {
            "my_languages": "872854"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You can use query_string

```
{
  "size": 30,
  "from": 0,
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "(8728431) AND (872854) AND (872845)",
      "default_field": "my_languages"
    }
  }
}
```

If you really want to pass a array, you could use script also, but you have to benchmark performance first, this seems to work:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": {
            "script": {
              "script": {
                "lang": "painless",
                "source": "def x = doc['my_languages']; def list_to_check = ['8728431', '872854', '872845']; def do_not_return = true; for(int i = 0; i < list_to_check.length; i++) { if(!x.contains(list_to_check[i])) {do_not_return = false;}} return do_not_return;"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you @LeBigCat for your response, I added mapping and test data  Please check it. Thank You.

Comment: Sorry it is not getting any records even there are matching records. Thanks again

Comment: Oh, this is an arary, my bad, i edit the answer

Comment: Thank You @LeBigCat and yes I can do that. I mentioned it in my question. But is there any way we can pass directly an array and do it? If I have 20 items it is becoming a big messy query.

Comment: I am a little tired :), i add a query_string solution ;)

Comment: oh Ok so there is no way directly we can pass an array to elasticsearch for "and" condition.

Comment: You cant, the only way i found if you want to pass a array is a script (edited). Last solution i see would be to use the copy_to feature, to copy all elements of your array in a text fields, and use a match / minimumshouldmatch 100% query.

Comment: Thank You @LeBigCat